(Arch)Linux always going to sleep again after first resume
I'm using Arch Linux. I recently made some updates which I skipped for a while but that led to a strange behaviour. Sadly I have no idea what really causes this phenomenon.
When I put the computer into sleep mode and wake it up, it always goes into suspend mode again. When I wake it up again afterwards it all works fine. So something is wrong only at the first wake-up after manual suspension.
The first resume happens either via USB input (mouse click etc) or when pressing the power button. The result is the same: it goes to suspend again right after a moment.
I checked the journalctl which looks like that:
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Freezing user space processes
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: Entering standby power mode
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 16 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 17 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 18 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 19 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 20 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 21 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 22 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 23 is now offline
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU1 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x8
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU2 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x9
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU3 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x10
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU4 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x11
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU5 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x18
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU6 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x19
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU7 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x20
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU8 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x21
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU9 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x28
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU10 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x29
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU11 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x30
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU12 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0x31
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU13 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0x38
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU14 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0x39
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU15 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 16 APIC 0x40
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: core: cpu_atom PMU driver: PEBS-via-PT 
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... version:                5
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... bit width:              48
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... generic registers:      6
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... fixed-purpose events:   3
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ... event mask:             000000070000003f
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU16 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 17 APIC 0x42
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU17 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 18 APIC 0x44
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU18 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 19 APIC 0x46
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU19 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 20 APIC 0x48
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU20 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 21 APIC 0x4a
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU21 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 22 APIC 0x4c
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU22 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 23 APIC 0x4e
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: CPU23 is up
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x411, Reinit
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: nvme nvme1: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/tgl_guc_70.bin version 70.20.0
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: nvme nvme1: 24/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC: authenticated for all workloads
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: submission enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: SLPC enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: RC enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: mei_me 0000:00:16.0: hbm: dma setup response: failure = 3 REJECTED
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: nvme nvme0: 24/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-14: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: Entering active power mode
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: ata5.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-2: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 2-9: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6.1: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: igc 0000:06:00.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 2-9.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 06]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0x86500000-0x866fffff]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 07]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0x86700000-0x867fffff]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1a.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1a.0:   bridge window [mem 0x86800000-0x868fffff]
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: mei_pxp 0000:00:16.0-fbf6fcf1-96cf-4e2e-a6a6-1bab8cbe36b1: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_pxp_tee_component_ops [i915])
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 2-9.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 70
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: PM: suspend exit
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 0
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-1040-0041.sfi
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 120-18.24
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_hq
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-logind[789]: Suspend key pressed short.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_sq
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-sleep[746245]: System returned from sleep operation 'suspend'.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_mq
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-sleep[746245]: Successfully thawed unit 'user.slice'.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo pulseaudio[1550]: org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.UnregisterBatteryProvider() Failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject:Method "UnregisterBatteryProvider" with signature "o" on interface "org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1" doesn't exist
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/faststream
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.52 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo bluetoothd[785]: Battery Provider Manager destroyed
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Starting Update locate database...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6.2: USB disconnect, device number 54
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 55
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1137]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1137]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-journald[527]: Time jumped backwards, rotating.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo ModemManager[851]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Aug 05 17:29:58 gordo systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo ModemManager[851]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo ModemManager[851]: <msg> [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3': Device support check task already available for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3'
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo ModemManager[851]: <msg> [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0': Device support check task already available for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:06:00.0'
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-logind[789]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.0233] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.0233] device (eno1): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.0234] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.0234] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.0234] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed no lease
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-logind[789]: The system will suspend now!
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo dnsmasq[1096]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.1565] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: sdb: detected capacity change from 2999623680 to 0
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2022] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2324] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2326] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to D2:5B:9C:00:D0:91 (scanning)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2327] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2327] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged-sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2328] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 88:D8:2E:7A:43:CE (unmanage)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo NetworkManager[783]: <info>  [1722871799.2329] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-sleep[746397]: Successfully froze unit 'user.slice'.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd-sleep[746397]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.025 seconds
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: updatedb.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo systemd[1]: Finished Update locate database.
Aug 05 17:29:59 gordo kernel: usb 1-6.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 56

At this time the computer is in standby again and I press the power button again a few seconds later. NOTE:I don't seem to have my USB devices available at that moment so I can't wake it up via mouse click or keyboard. Journalctl shows these lines:
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Freezing user space processes
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1233088 usecs
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 15669 usecs
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-1040-0041.ddc
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2024.18 buildtype 1 build 81528
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: usb 1-6-port2: connect-debounce failed
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 2.656 seconds)
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: ata5.00: Entering standby power mode
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 05 17:30:17 gordo kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
...

The journal from the second resume looks "normal" with the same bluetooth errors - so I doubt it is the cause.
Any suggestions what I might check? Or does anyone see already which of these events might cause the direct suspend?

Do you have any systemd services that run after resuming? As in, any that set WantedBy=suspend.target, After=suspend.target. I have the same issue and it only started occuring after I created one of these services.

How could I check that? At least non that I knew of but maybe some software added something.

You could check all units listed in systemctl list-units. Or try grepping for this particular line in /etc/systemd or similar (wherever Arch has its systemd files).
